# D3D, Vertex From Mesh

Tags: mesh, direct3d

By Using D3DXLoadMeshFromX, I could load a mesh's subsets, materials, textures,... So I succeed Draw Mesh.

What I want to know is that Mesh's Vertex Infomation(for picking).

My Code is..

```
    m_pMesh->PDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9     pVB;
    m_pMesh->GetVertexBuffer(&pVB);

    void* Vtx = nullptr;
    pVB->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&Vtx, 0);
```

Then I want to know Vtx's information like Vertex, but Vtx is void pointer...
If I know struct of that mesh I might know vertex info, but I don't

I'm sorry if I answer too vaguely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the legacy DirectX SDK's sample in `Samples\C++\Direct3D\Pick`.

You have to use `CloneMeshFVF` to reformat the vertex data layout and you need to make sure you specify `D3DXMESH_VB_MANAGED` or `D3DXMESH_VB_SYSTEMMEM` so that you can actually lock the resulting VB.

```
   LPD3DXMESH pMesh;

    g_Mesh.GetMesh()->CloneMeshFVF( D3DXMESH_MANAGED,
                                    g_Mesh.GetMesh()->GetFVF(), pD3Device, &pMesh );

    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 pVB;
    LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 pIB;

    pMesh->GetVertexBuffer( &pVB );
    pMesh->GetIndexBuffer( &pIB );

    WORD* pIndices;
    D3DVERTEX* pVertices;

    pIB->Lock( 0, 0, ( void** )&pIndices, 0 );
    pVB->Lock( 0, 0, ( void** )&pVertices, 0 );
```

Keep in mind that picking uses a CPU memory copy of the vertex data, while rendering uses a video memory copy. In real-time applications, you typically do not use the full complexity of the rendering model for collision, but a simplified collision model that you never need to render and only keep in memory.

Comment: Thanks!!! I changed 'g_Mesh.GetMesh()->GetFVF()' to                  DWORD VTXFVF_TEX = D3DFVF_XYZ  | D3DFVF_TEX0; Then pVertices have only vertex info what I wanted.

Comment: Again, I really appreciate. Anyway I am a little curious of what you comment on picking. When Picking, I might render all vertex data and at the same time find triangles' of vertices. Will it be any problem.

Comment: You need a GPU copy of the vertex buffer to perform rendering, including positions, vertex normal, texcoords, vertex colors, etc. For picking you need a CPU copy of only the positions and indices (for indexed triangles).

Comment: I understand. Thanks you so much.